# hall.dll errors

Tags: windows-7

I am getting frequent BSoDs, mostly with hall.dll errors.  I have Dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 7 SP1.  The following file, werfault, is shown below.  Can anyone help me work out what is wrong?

```
Version=1
EventType=BlueScreen
EventTime=129987824768810026
ReportType=4
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=1c3e1c58-3b30-11e2-9074-002219f61870
IntegratorReportIdentifier=113012-32557-01
Response.type=4
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=2057
UI[2]=C:\Windows\system32\wer.dll
UI[3]=Windows has recovered from an unexpected shutdown
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=&Check for solution
UI[6]=&Check later
UI[7]=Cancel
UI[8]=Windows has recovered from an unexpected shutdown
UI[9]=A problem caused Windows to stop working correctly.  Windows will notify you if a solution is available.
UI[10]=Close
Sec[0].Key=BCCode
Sec[0].Value=a
Sec[1].Key=BCP1
Sec[1].Value=0000000000000000
Sec[2].Key=BCP2
Sec[2].Value=0000000000000002
Sec[3].Key=BCP3
Sec[3].Value=0000000000000000
Sec[4].Key=BCP4
Sec[4].Value=FFFFF80002C0E477
Sec[5].Key=OS Version
Sec[5].Value=6_1_7601
Sec[6].Key=Service Pack
Sec[6].Value=1_0
Sec[7].Key=Product
Sec[7].Value=768_1
File[0].CabName=113012-32557-01.dmp
File[0].Path=113012-32557-01.dmp
File[0].Flags=589826
File[0].Type=2
File[0].Original.Path=C:\Windows\Minidump\113012-32557-01.dmp
File[1].CabName=sysdata.xml
File[1].Path=WER-75941-0.sysdata.xml
File[1].Flags=589826
File[1].Type=5
File[1].Original.Path=C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-75941-0.sysdata.xml
File[2].CabName=Report.cab
File[2].Path=Report.cab
File[2].Flags=196608
File[2].Type=7
File[2].Original.Path=Report.cab
FriendlyEventName=Shut down unexpectedly
ConsentKey=BlueScreen
AppName=Windows
AppPath=C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe

*********From the minidump file****
RAX = fffff88002f22150
RBX = fffffa80074141f0
RCX = 000000000000000a
RDX = 0000000000000000
RSI = fffffa8007278180
RDI = 0000000000000001
R9 = 0000000000000000
R10 = fffff80002c0e477
R11 = 0000000000000000
R12 = fffffa800523e7a0
R13 = 0000000000001000
R14 = 0000000000000028
R15 = fffffa80074141f0
RBP = fffff88002f22210
RIP = fffff80002cd3fc0
RSP = fffff88002f22048
SS = 0000
GS = 002b
FS = 0053
ES = 002b
DS = 002b
CS = 0010
Flags = 00200286


fffff800`02e99ac0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99ad0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99ae0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99af0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99b00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99b10  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99b20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99b30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99b40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e99b50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                ............    


fffff800`02e81928  00 00 00 00                                        ....            


fffff800`02e81924  00 00 00 00                                        ....            


fffff800`02e0a880  37 36 30 31 2E 31 37 39 34 34 2E 61 6D 64 36 34    7601.17944.amd64
fffff800`02e0a890  66 72 65 2E 77 69 6E 37 73 70 31 5F 67 64 72 2E    fre.win7sp1_gdr.
fffff800`02e0a8a0  31 32 30 38 33 30 2D 30 33 33 33 00 00 00 00 00    120830-0333.....
fffff800`02e0a8b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a8c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a8d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a8e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a8f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a900  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a910  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a920  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a930  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a940  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a950  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
fffff800`02e0a960  35 36 65 38 62 61 31 33 2D 37 30 32 39 2D 34 37    56e8ba13-7029-47
fffff800`02e0a970  32 38 2D 61 35 30 36 2D 32 64 64 62 34 61 30 63    28-a506-2ddb4a0c


fffff800`02c0e000  C5 0F 85 79 02 00 00 8B 9C 24 90 00 00 00 E9 A5    ...y.....$......
fffff800`02c0e010  00 00 00 44 2B C3 45 33 C9 E8 5E 14 00 00 49 3B    ...D+.E3..^...I;
fffff800`02c0e020  C5 74 2B 44 8B 8C 24 90 00 00 00 48 8B C8 41 8D    .t+D..$....H..A.
fffff800`02c0e030  51 FF 41 3B D5 76 0D 44 8B C2 49 83 E8 01 48 8B    Q.A;.v.D..I...H.
fffff800`02c0e040  49 08 75 F6 48 89 79 08 41 03 D9 48 8B F8 3B DD    I.u.H.y.A..H..;.
fffff800`02c0e050  75 08 48 8B C7 E9 26 02 00 00 48 8B 96 98 00 00    u.H...&...H.....
fffff800`02c0e060  00 48 8D 84 24 90 00 00 00 44 8B C5 48 89 44 24    .H..$....D..H.D$
fffff800`02c0e070  28 44 2B C3 45 33 C9 48 8B CE 44 88 6C 24 20 E8    (D+.E3.H..D.l$ .
fffff800`02c0e080  CC 14 00 00 49 3B C5 74 2B 44 8B 8C 24 90 00 00    ....I;.t+D..$...
fffff800`02c0e090  00 48 8B C8 41 8D 51 FF 41 3B D5 76 0D 44 8B C2    .H..A.Q.A;.v.D..
fffff800`02c0e0a0  49 83 E8 01 48 8B 49 08 75 F6 48 89 79 08 41 03    I...H.I.u.H.y.A.
fffff800`02c0e0b0  D9 48 8B F8 3B DD 74 9A 44 38 AE 28 01 00 00 0F    .H..;.t.D8.(....
fffff800`02c0e0c0  85 DF 00 00 00 48 8D 44 24 30 4C 8D 8C 24 A0 00    .....H.D$0L..$..
fffff800`02c0e0d0  00 00 4C 8D 84 24 A8 00 00 00 8B D5 48 8B CE 48    ..L..$......H..H
fffff800`02c0e0e0  89 44 24 20 E8 F7 1F 00 00 8B F8 89 84 24 90 00    .D$ .........$..
fffff800`02c0e0f0  00 00 41 3B C5 0F 84 83 01 00 00 4C 8B A4 24 A8    ..A;.......L..$.
fffff800`02c0e100  00 00 00 44 8B 84 24 A0 00 00 00 48 8B 8E 98 00    ...D..$....H....
fffff800`02c0e110  00 00 49 8B D4 44 8B C8 E8 DB 1B 00 00 49 3B C5    ..I..D.......I;.
fffff800`02c0e120  74 35 48 8B 96 98 00 00 00 48 8D 84 24 90 00 00    t5H......H..$...
fffff800`02c0e130  00 41 B1 01 48 89 44 24 28 44 8B C5 48 8B CE 44    .A..H.D$(D..H..D
fffff800`02c0e140  88 6C 24 20 E8 43 12 00 00 49 3B C5 0F 84 2C 01    .l$ .C...I;...,.
fffff800`02c0e150  00 00 E9 29 01 00 00 48 8B 5C 24 30 49 3B DD 74    ...)...H.\$0I;.t
fffff800`02c0e160  2A 4D 3B E5 74 0C 48 8B D3 49 8B CC FF 15 AE CE    *M;.t.H..I......
fffff800`02c0e170  01 00 48 8B CB FF 15 95 CF 01 00 33 D2 48 8B CB    ..H........3.H..
fffff800`02c0e180  FF 15 AA CE 01 00 E9 F3 00 00 00 C1 E7 0C 41 B8    ..............A.
fffff800`02c0e190  01 00 00 00 49 8B CC 8B D7 FF 15 99 CE 01 00 E9    ....I...........
fffff800`02c0e1a0  DA 00 00 00 2B EB 33 C9 41 B8 48 61 6C 20 8B D5    ....+.3.A.Hal ..
fffff800`02c0e1b0  44 8B FD 48 C1 E2 03 FF 15 33 D4 01 00 4C 8B F0    D..H.....3...L..
fffff800`02c0e1c0  49 3B C5 0F 84 8F 00 00 00 45 8B E5 41 3B ED 76    I;.......E..A;.v
fffff800`02c0e1d0  3F 4C 8B E8 BA 00 10 00 00 B9 04 00 00 00 41 B8    ?L............A.
fffff800`02c0e1e0  48 61 6C 20 FF 15 06 D4 01 00 49 89 45 00 48 85    Hal ......I.E.H.
fffff800`02c0e1f0  C0 74 39 48 8B C8 FF 15 BC CE 01 00 48 C1 E8 20    .t9H........H.. 
fffff800`02c0e200  85 C0 75 28 41 FF C4 49 83 C5 08 44 3B E5 72 C4    ..u(A..I...D;.r.
fffff800`02c0e210  48 8B 8E 98 00 00 00 44 8B C5 BA 01 00 00 00 E8    H......D........
fffff800`02c0e220  58 19 00 00 4C 8B E8 48 85 C0 75 6C 45 33 ED 45    X...L..H..ulE3.E
fffff800`02c0e230  3B E5 76 19 49 8B EE 48 8B 4D 00 33 D2 FF 15 ED    ;.v.I..H.M.3....
fffff800`02c0e240  CD 01 00 48 83 C5 08 49 83 EC 01 75 EA 33 D2 49    ...H...I...u.3.I
fffff800`02c0e250  8B CE FF 15 D8 CD 01 00 41 3B DD 76 21 8B EB 48    ........A;.v!..H
fffff800`02c0e260  8B 96 98 00 00 00 48 8B 5F 08 4C 8B C7 48 8B CE    ......H._.L..H..
fffff800`02c0e270  E8 2B 15 00 00 48 83 ED 01 48 8B FB 75 E1 33 C0    .+...H...H..u.3.
fffff800`02c0e280  48 8B 9C 24 98 00 00 00 48 83 C4 50 41 5F 41 5E    H..$....H..PA_A^
fffff800`02c0e290  41 5D 41 5C 5F 5E 5D C3 8D 4D FF 85 C9 74 0C 8B    A]A\_^]..M...t..
fffff800`02c0e2a0  D1 48 83 EA 01 48 8B 40 08 75 F6 48 89 78 08 49    .H...H.@.u.H.x.I
fffff800`02c0e2b0  8B FD 85 ED 74 29 49 8B DE 48 8B 0B FF 15 F6 CD    ....t)I..H......
fffff800`02c0e2c0  01 00 41 89 45 00 48 8B 03 48 83 C3 08 48 83 C8    ..A.E.H..H...H..
fffff800`02c0e2d0  0F 49 83 EF 01 49 89 45 10 4D 8B 6D 08 75 DA 48    .I...I.E.M.m.u.H
fffff800`02c0e2e0  8B 8E 98 00 00 00 48 8D 54 24 38 48 83 C1 78 FF    ......H.T$8H..x.
fffff800`02c0e2f0  15 83 CD 01 00 4C 8B 9E 98 00 00 00 48 8D 4C 24    .....L......H.L$
fffff800`02c0e300  38 41 01 AB D0 00 00 00 FF 15 3A CD 01 00 33 D2    8A........:...3.
fffff800`02c0e310  49 8B CE FF 15 17 CD 01 00 E9 34 FD FF FF 90 90    I.........4.....
fffff800`02c0e320  90 90 90 90 45 85 C0 74 43 48 89 5C 24 08 48 89    ....E..tCH.\$.H.
fffff800`02c0e330  74 24 10 57 48 83 EC 20 48 8B F1 41 8B F8 48 8B    t$.WH.. H..A..H.
fffff800`02c0e340  5A 08 4C 8B C2 48 8B 96 98 00 00 00 48 8B CE E8    Z.L..H......H...
fffff800`02c0e350  4C 14 00 00 48 83 EF 01 48 8B D3 75 E1 48 8B 5C    L...H...H..u.H.\
fffff800`02c0e360  24 30 48 8B 74 24 38 48 83 C4 20 5F C3 90 90 90    $0H.t$8H.. _....
fffff800`02c0e370  90 90 90 90 48 8B C4 48 89 58 08 48 89 68 10 48    ....H..H.X.H.h.H
fffff800`02c0e380  89 70 18 48 89 78 20 41 54 41 55 4C 8B D9 4D 8B    .p.H.x ATAUL..M.
fffff800`02c0e390  E0 48 8B F2 B9 FF 0F 00 00 4D 85 DB 75 08 4C 8B    .H.......M..u.L.
fffff800`02c0e3a0  D1 40 32 FF EB 12 4D 8B 93 88 00 00 00 41 8A BB    .@2...M......A..
fffff800`02c0e3b0  91 00 00 00 49 C1 EA 0C 44 8B 44 24 38 41 8B C1    ....I...D.D$8A..
fffff800`02c0e3c0  4C 2B 4E 20 23 C1 49 C1 E9 0C 41 BD 00 10 00 00    L+N #.I...A.....
fffff800`02c0e3d0  41 8B D5 41 8B E9 2B D0 8B CA 4C 39 54 EE 30 76    A..A..+...L9T.0v
fffff800`02c0e3e0  04 33 C9 EB 4F 41 3B D0 73 43 4C 8D 4C EE 38 4D    .3..OA;.sCL.L.8M
fffff800`02c0e3f0  39 11 77 39 49 8B 59 F8 48 8D 43 01 49 3B 01 75    9.w9I.Y.H.C.I;.u
fffff800`02c0e400  2C 48 8B C3 49 33 01 48 A9 00 00 F0 FF 75 1E 40    ,H..I3.H.....u.@
fffff800`02c0e410  80 FF 01 74 0C 49 33 19 48 F7 C3 F0 FF FF FF 75    ...t.I3.H......u
fffff800`02c0e420  0C 41 03 CD 49 83 C1 08 41 3B C8 72 C2 41 3B C8    .A..I...A;.r.A;.
fffff800`02c0e430  41 0F 47 C8 4D 85 DB 0F 84 92 00 00 00 41 80 BB    A.G.M........A..
fffff800`02c0e440  28 01 00 00 00 0F 84 84 00 00 00 4C 39 54 EE 30    (..........L9T.0
fffff800`02c0e450  76 7D 8B CA 48 8D 44 EE 38 41 3B D0 73 11 4C 39    v}..H.D.8A;.s.L9
fffff800`02c0e460  10 76 0C 41 03 CD 48 83 C0 08 41 3B C8 72 EF 49    .v.A..H...A;.r.I
fffff800`02c0e470  8B 44 24 18 41 3B C8 44 8B 08 4C 8B 50 08 41 0F    .D$.A;.D..L.P.A.
fffff800`02c0e480  47 C8 41 C1 E9 0C EB 3A 45 8B 02 41 8D 41 01 41    G.A....:E..A.A.A
fffff800`02c0e490  C1 E8 0C 44 3B C0 75 2E 41 8B C0 41 33 C1 A9 00    ...D;.u.A..A3...
fffff800`02c0e4a0  00 F0 FF 75 21 40 80 FF 01 74 0D 41 8B C0 41 33    ...u!@...t.A..A3
fffff800`02c0e4b0  C1 A9 F0 FF FF FF 75 0E 4D 8B 52 08 45 8B C8 41    ......u.M.R.E..A
fffff800`02c0e4c0  03 D5 3B D1 72 C2 3B D1 0F 47 D1 8B C2 EB 02 8B    ..;.r.;..G......
fffff800`02c0e4d0  C1 48 8B 5C 24 18 48 8B 6C 24 20 48 8B 74 24 28    .H.\$.H.l$ H.t$(
fffff800`02c0e4e0  48 8B 7C 24 30 41 5D 41 5C C3 90 90 90 90 90 90    H.|$0A]A\.......
fffff800`02c0e4f0  48 89 5C 24 08 48 89 6C 24 10 48 89 74 24 18 57    H.\$.H.l$.H.t$.W
fffff800`02c0e500  41 54 41 55 48 83 EC 30 48 8B 5C 24 70 4D 8B E1    ATAUH..0H.\$pM..
fffff800`02c0e510  49 8B F0 8B 03 4C 8B EA 48 8B E9 89 44 24 20 E8    I....L..H...D$ .
fffff800`02c0e520  50 FE FF FF 49 8B CC 89 03 49 2B 4D 20 8B F8 48    P...I....I+M ..H
fffff800`02c0e530  C1 E9 0C 8B C9 49 8B 54 CD 30 49 8B CC 48 C1 E2    .....I.T.0I..H..
fffff800`02c0e540  0C 81 E1 FF 0F 00 00 48 03 D1 48 85 F6 74 72 48    .......H..H..trH
fffff800`02c0e550  39 95 88 00 00 00 73 69 4C 8B 4E 18 48 8B 84 24    9.....siL.N.H..$
fffff800`02c0e560  80 00 00 00 41 8B DC 41 8B 09 81 E3 FF 0F 00 00    ....A..A........
fffff800`02c0e570  03 CB 80 7C 24 78 01 48 89 08 75 17 4D 8B C4 49    ...|$x.H..u.M..I
fffff800`02c0e580  8B D5 48 8B CD C6 44 24 28 01 89 7C 24 20 E8 C5    ..H...D$(..|$ ..
fffff800`02c0e590  06 00 00 8B C7 C1 EF 0C 25 FF 0F 00 00 8D 8C 18    ........%.......
fffff800`02c0e5a0  FF 0F 00 00 48 8B 46 18 C1 E9 0C 03 CF 74 0C 8B    ....H.F......t..
fffff800`02c0e5b0  D1 48 83 EA 01 48 8B 40 08 75 F6 48 89 46 18 EB    .H...H.@.u.H.F..
fffff800`02c0e5c0  0B 48 8B 84 24 80 00 00 00 48 89 10 48 8B 5C 24    .H..$....H..H.\$
fffff800`02c0e5d0  50 48 8B 6C 24 58 48 8B 74 24 60 48 83 C4 30 41    PH.l$XH.t$`H..0A
fffff800`02c0e5e0  5D 41 5C 5F C3 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 4D 85 C0 0F    ]A\_........M...
fffff800`02c0e5f0  84 09 01 00 00 48 8B C4 48 89 58 08 48 89 68 10    .....H..H.X.H.h.
fffff800`02c0e600  48 89 70 18 48 89 78 20 41 54 41 55 41 56 48 83    H.p.H.x ATAUAVH.
fffff800`02c0e610  EC 30 44 8A 64 24 78 49 8B D8 49 8B F1 4C 8B EA    .0D.d$xI..I..L..
fffff800`02c0e620  4C 8B F1 49 89 58 18 41 80 FC 01 0F 84 AF 00 00    L..I.X.A........
fffff800`02c0e630  00 8B 7C 24 70 85 FF 0F 84 9F 00 00 00 4C 8B CE    ..|$p........L..
fffff800`02c0e640  4C 8B C3 49 8B D5 49 8B CE 89 7C 24 20 E8 22 FD    L..I..I...|$ .".
fffff800`02c0e650  FF FF 48 8B CE 49 2B 4D 20 8B E8 48 C1 E9 0C 8B    ..H..I+M ..H....
fffff800`02c0e660  C9 49 8B 54 CD 30 48 8B CE 48 C1 E2 0C 81 E1 FF    .I.T.0H..H......
fffff800`02c0e670  0F 00 00 48 03 D1 49 39 96 88 00 00 00 73 52 4C    ...H..I9.....sRL
fffff800`02c0e680  8B 4B 18 4C 8B C6 49 8B D5 49 8B CE 44 88 64 24    .K.L..I..I..D.d$
fffff800`02c0e690  28 89 6C 24 20 E8 BE 05 00 00 8B C5 44 8B DE 25    (.l$ .......D..%
fffff800`02c0e6a0  FF 0F 00 00 41 81 E3 FF 0F 00 00 41 8D 8C 03 FF    ....A......A....
fffff800`02c0e6b0  0F 00 00 8B C5 C1 E8 0C C1 E9 0C 03 C8 48 8B 43    .............H.C
fffff800`02c0e6c0  18 74 0A 48 83 E9 01 48 8B 40 08 75 F6 48 89 43    .t.H...H.@.u.H.C
fffff800`02c0e6d0  18 48 03 F5 2B FD 0F 85 61 FF FF FF 48 89 5B 18    .H..+...a...H.[.
fffff800`02c0e6e0  48 8B 5C 24 50 48 8B 6C 24 58 48 8B 74 24 60 48    H.\$PH.l$XH.t$`H
fffff800`02c0e6f0  8B 7C 24 68 48 83 C4 30 41 5E 41 5D 41 5C C3 90    .|$hH..0A^A]A\..
fffff800`02c0e700  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 48 89 54 24 10 53 55 56    ........H.T$.SUV
fffff800`02c0e710  57 41 54 41 55 41 56 41 57 48 83 EC 58 48 8B F2    WATAUAVAWH..XH..
fffff800`02c0e720  48 8B D9 48 8D 54 24 30 48 8D 0D B9 67 02 00 45    H..H.T$0H...g..E
fffff800`02c0e730  8B E1 49 8B F8 4C 89 84 24 B0 00 00 00 FF 15 35    ..I..L..$......5
fffff800`02c0e740  C9 01 00 4C 8B 2D 86 67 02 00 4C 8B 35 77 67 02    ...L.-.g..L.5wg.
fffff800`02c0e750  00 48 8B C6 44 8B C6 48 2B 43 20 41 81 E0 FF 0F    .H..D..H+C A....
fffff800`02c0e760  00 00 BD 00 10 00 00 48 C1 E8 0C 45 89 45 2C 8B    .......H...E.E,.
fffff800`02c0e770  CD 8B C0 41 2B C8 41 89 4D 28 4C 8D 4C C3 30 48    ...A+.A.M(L.L.0H
fffff800`02c0e780  8B C6 48 25 00 F0 FF FF 49 89 45 20 49 89 46 20    ..H%....I.E I.F 
fffff800`02c0e790  45 89 46 2C 41 89 4E 28 44 89 84 24 B8 00 00 00    E.F,A.N(D..$....
fffff800`02c0e7a0  4C 89 8C 24 A0 00 00 00 45 85 E4 0F 84 90 01 00    L..$....E.......
fffff800`02c0e7b0  00 48 8B 5F 10 48 81 E3 00 F0 FF FF 75 3C 8B 07    .H._.H......u<..
fffff800`02c0e7c0  48 8B 0D 49 67 02 00 44 8D 4B 01 48 C1 E8 0C 4D    H..Ig..D.K.H...M
fffff800`02c0e7d0  8B C6 BA 48 61 6C 20 49 89 46 30 FF 15 DF C8 01    ...Hal I.F0.....
fffff800`02c0e7e0  00 48 8B D8 48 85 C0 0F 84 36 01 00 00 4C 8B 8C    .H..H....6...L..
fffff800`02c0e7f0  24 A0 00 00 00 41 B7 01 EB 09 41 8B C0 48 03 D8    $....A....A..H..
fffff800`02c0e800  45 32 FF 49 8B 01 33 FF 49 89 45 30 48 8B 0D C5    E2.I..3.I.E0H...
fffff800`02c0e810  66 02 00 44 8B CF 4D 8B C5 BA 48 61 6C 20 FF 15    f..D..M...Hal ..
fffff800`02c0e820  9C C8 01 00 48 8B F0 48 85 C0 75 24 FF C7 83 FF    ....H..H..u$....
fffff800`02c0e830  06 7C D9 48 21 44 24 20 45 33 C9 41 B8 01 EF 00    .|.H!D$ E3.A....
fffff800`02c0e840  00 48 8B D5 B9 AC 00 00 00 FF 15 A1 CA 01 00 CC    .H..............
fffff800`02c0e850  8B FD 2B BC 24 B8 00 00 00 44 3B E7 41 0F 42 FC    ..+.$....D;.A.B.
fffff800`02c0e860  80 BC 24 C0 00 00 00 01 8B EF 44 8B C7 75 0E 48    ..$.......D..u.H
fffff800`02c0e870  8B D0 48 8B CB FF 15 AD 33 02 00 EB 0B 48 8B D3    ..H.....3....H..
fffff800`02c0e880  48 8B C8 E8 C8 A6 01 00 4D 8B C5 BA 48 61 6C 20    H.......M...Hal 
fffff800`02c0e890  48 8B CE FF 15 47 C8 01 00 41 80 FF 01 75 11 4D    H....G...A...u.M
fffff800`02c0e8a0  8B C6 BA 48 61 6C 20 48 8B CB FF 15 30 C8 01 00    ...Hal H....0...
fffff800`02c0e8b0  48 8B 84 24 A8 00 00 00 4C 8B 8C 24 A0 00 00 00    H..$....L..$....
fffff800`02c0e8c0  44 2B E7 48 8B BC 24 B0 00 00 00 48 03 C5 BD 00    D+.H..$....H....
fffff800`02c0e8d0  10 00 00 48 8B 7F 08 49 83 C1 08 45 33 C0 44 3B    ...H..I...E3.D;
fffff800`02c0e8e0  E5 48 8B C8 41 8B D4 0F 47 D5 48 81 E1 00 F0 FF    .H..A...G.H.....
fffff800`02c0e8f0  FF 48 89 84 24 A8 00 00 00 49 89 4D 20 41 89 55    .H..$....I.M A.U
fffff800`02c0e900  28 25 FF 0F 00 00 41 89 45 2C 49 89 4E 20 41 89    (%....A.E,I.N A.
fffff800`02c0e910  46 2C 41 89 56 28 48 89 BC 24 B0 00 00 00 E9 75    F,A.V(H..$.....u
fffff800`02c0e920  FE FF FF 48 83 64 24 20 00 45 33 C9 41 B8 00 EF    ...H.d$ .E3.A...
fffff800`02c0e930  00 00 48 8B D5 B9 AC 00 00 00 FF 15 B0 C9 01 00    ..H.............
fffff800`02c0e940  CC 48 8D 4C 24 30 FF 15 FC C6 01 00 48 83 C4 58    .H.L$0......H..X
fffff800`02c0e950  41 5F 41 5E 41 5D 41 5C 5F 5E 5D 5B C3 90 90 90    A_A^A]A\_^][....
fffff800`02c0e960  90 90 90 90 48 89 5C 24 08 48 89 6C 24 10 48 89    ....H.\$.H.l$.H.
fffff800`02c0e970  74 24 18 57 41 54 41 55 48 83 EC 50 33 C0 49 8B    t$.WATAUH..P3.I.
fffff800`02c0e980  F9 41 8B F0 4C 8B E2 48 8B CA 49 C7 C3 00 F0 FF    .A..L..H..I.....
fffff800`02c0e990  FF 45 85 C0 74 10 4C 85 59 10 74 0A 48 8B 49 08    .E..t.L.Y.t.H.I.
fffff800`02c0e9a0  FF C0 3B C6 72 F0 3B C6 75 09 49 83 21 00 E9 FB    ..;.r.;.u.I.!...
fffff800`02c0e9b0  00 00 00 65 48 8B 04 25 20 00 00 00 33 C9 44 8B    ...eH..% ...3.D.
fffff800`02c0e9c0  50 24 48 8B 05 F7 64 02 00 4A 8B 2C D0 4C 8D 4D    P$H...d..J.,.L.M
fffff800`02c0e9d0  30 45 85 C0 74 22 4C 8B C6 4C 85 5A 10 75 0F 8B    0E..t"L..L.Z.u..
fffff800`02c0e9e0  02 FF C1 48 C1 E8 0C 49 89 01 49 83 C1 08 49 83    ...H...I..I...I.
fffff800`02c0e9f0  E8 01 48 8B 52 08 75 E1 33 DB C1 E1 0C 41 B5 01    ..H.R.u.3....A..
fffff800`02c0ea00  48 21 5D 20 21 5D 2C 89 4D 28 44 38 2D 07 65 02    H!] !],.M(D8-.e.
fffff800`02c0ea10  00 75 10 48 8B 05 C6 64 02 00 4A 8B 1C D0 E9 29    .u.H...d..J....)
fffff800`02c0ea20  01 00 00 48 8D 0D D6 64 02 00 FF 15 50 C6 01 00    ...H...d....P...
fffff800`02c0ea30  48 85 C0 0F 85 F9 00 00 00 44 8D 40 01 45 33 C9    H........D.@.E3.
fffff800`02c0ea40  33 D2 48 8B CD C7 44 24 28 20 00 00 00 21 5C 24    3.H...D$( ...!\$
fffff800`02c0ea50  20 FF 15 71 C6 01 00 4C 8B D8 48 85 C0 74 69 45     ..q...L..H..tiE
fffff800`02c0ea60  32 ED 49 8B D3 85 F6 74 36 48 8B CE 49 F7 44 24    2.I....t6H..I.D$
fffff800`02c0ea70  10 00 F0 FF FF 75 1D 41 8B 44 24 10 25 EF 0F 00    .....u.A.D$.%...
fffff800`02c0ea80  00 48 0B C2 48 83 C8 10 48 81 C2 00 10 00 00 49    .H..H...H......I
fffff800`02c0ea90  89 44 24 10 48 83 E9 01 4D 8B 64 24 08 75 CD 48    .D$.H...M.d$.u.H
fffff800`02c0eaa0  89 2F 4C 89 5F 08 48 89 5F 10 44 88 6F 30 4C 8D    ./L._.H._.D.o0L.
fffff800`02c0eab0  5C 24 50 49 8B 5B 20 49 8B 6B 28 49 8B 73 30 49    \$PI.[ I.k(I.s0I
fffff800`02c0eac0  8B E3 41 5D 41 5C 5F C3 48 8D 54 24 30 48 8D 0D    ..A]A\_.H.T$0H..
fffff800`02c0ead0  4C 64 02 00 FF 15 66 C5 01 00 48 8B 15 FF 63 02    Ld....f...H...c.
fffff800`02c0eae0  00 44 8B 0D 10 64 02 00 48 8B 02 B9 01 00 00 00    .D...d..H.......
fffff800`02c0eaf0  44 8B 40 18 44 3B C9 76 1E 48 83 C2 08 48 8B 02    D.@.D;.v.H...H..
fffff800`02c0eb00  44 39 40 18 7D 06 44 8B 40 18 8B D9 FF C1 48 83    D9@.}.D.@.....H.
fffff800`02c0eb10  C2 08 41 3B C9 72 E6 48 8D 4C 24 30 FF 15 0E C6    ..A;.r.H.L$0....
fffff800`02c0eb20  01 00 48 8B 05 B7 63 02 00 44 8B DB 4A 8B 1C D8    ..H...c..D..J...
fffff800`02c0eb30  EB 07 83 60 1C 00 48 8B D8 F0 83 43 18 01 48 8D    ...`..H....C..H.
fffff800`02c0eb40  57 18 48 8D 4B 20 FF 15 F4 C4 01 00 48 8B 4B 10    W.H.K ......H.K.
fffff800`02c0eb50  41 B9 01 00 00 00 4C 8B C5 BA 48 61 6C 20 FF 15    A.....L...Hal ..
fffff800`02c0eb60  5C C5 01 00 4C 8B D8 48 85 C0 0F 85 F2 FE FF FF    \...L..H........
fffff800`02c0eb70  48 21 44 24 20 45 33 C9 BA 00 10 00 00 B9 AC 00    H!D$ E3.........
fffff800`02c0eb80  00 00 41 B8 02 EF 00 00 FF 15 62 C7 01 00 CC 90    ..A.......b.....
fffff800`02c0eb90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 48 89 5C 24 08 48 89 6C    ........H.\$.H.l
fffff800`02c0eba0  24 18 48 89 74 24 20 57 48 83 EC 20 41 80 78 30    $.H.t$ WH.. A.x0
fffff800`02c0ebb0  00 49 8B F8 8B F2 48 8B D9 BD 01 00 00 00 75 0F    .I....H.......u.
fffff800`02c0ebc0  49 8B 10 49 8B 48 08 FF 15 53 C4 01 00 EB 4A 4D    I..I.H...S....JM
fffff800`02c0ebd0  8B 00 48 8B 4F 08 BA 48 61 6C 20 FF 15 FF C4 01    ..H.O..Hal .....
fffff800`02c0ebe0  00 80 3D 30 63 02 00 00 75 2F 48 8D 4F 18 FF 15    ..=0c...u/H.O...
fffff800`02c0ebf0  3C C5 01 00 48 8B 57 10 83 C8 FF F0 0F C1 42 18    <...H.W.......B.
fffff800`02c0ec00  83 C0 FF 75 14 F0 0F B1 6A 1C 75 0D 48 8D 0D ED    ...u....j.u.H...
fffff800`02c0ec10  62 02 00 FF 15 4F C4 01 00 85 F6 74 1E 48 8B CE    b....O.....t.H..
fffff800`02c0ec20  F6 43 10 10 74 0C 8B 43 10 25 EF 0F 00 00 48 89    .C..t..C.%....H.
fffff800`02c0ec30  43 10 48 2B CD 48 8B 5B 08 75 E5 48 8B 5C 24 30    C.H+.H.[.u.H.\$0
fffff800`02c0ec40  48 8B 6C 24 40 48 8B 74 24 48 48 83 C4 20 5F C3    H.l$@H.t$HH.. _.
fffff800`02c0ec50  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 48 89 5C 24 18 48 89 4C    ........H.\$.H.L
fffff800`02c0ec60  24 08 55 56 57 41 54 41 55 41 56 41 57 48 83 EC    $.UVWATAUAVAWH..
fffff800`02c0ec70  70 4D 8B F1 4D 8B E8 48 8B F2 4C 8B D1 44 0F 20    pM..M..H..L..D. 
fffff800`02c0ec80  C7 F6 42 0A 05 74 06 48 8B 5A 18 EB 2A 45 33 C9    ..B..t.H.Z..*E3.
fffff800`02c0ec90  33 D2 48 8B CE 45 8D 41 01 C7 44 24 28 20 00 00    3.H..E.A..D$( ..
fffff800`02c0eca0  00 83 64 24 20 00 FF 15 1C C4 01 00 4C 8B 94 24    ..d$ .......L..$
fffff800`02c0ecb0  B0 00 00 00 48 8B D8 BD 02 00 00 00 48 85 DB 75    ....H.......H..u
fffff800`02c0ecc0  4A 40 3A FD 76 1F 48 21 5C 24 20 45 33 C9 BA 00    J@:.v.H!\$ E3...
fffff800`02c0ecd0  10 00 00 B9 AC 00 00 00 41 B8 05 EF 00 00 FF 15    ........A.......
fffff800`02c0ece0  0C C6 01 00 CC 8A 84 24 D8 00 00 00 44 8B 8C 24    .......$....D..$
fffff800`02c0ecf0  D0 00 00 00 4D 8B C6 49 8B D5 48 8B CE 88 44 24    ....M..I..H...D$
fffff800`02c0ed00  20 E8 02 FA FF FF E9 4D 01 00 00 44 8B BC 24 D0     ......M...D..$.
fffff800`02c0ed10  00 00 00 BA FF 0F 00 00 41 8B CD 23 CA 41 8B C7    ........A..#.A..
fffff800`02c0ed20  C6 84 24 B8 00 00 00 00 23 C2 44 8D A4 01 FF 0F    ..$.....#.D.....
fffff800`02c0ed30  00 00 41 8B C7 41 C1 EC 0C C1 E8 0C 44 03 E0 44    ..A..A......D..D
fffff800`02c0ed40  89 64 24 30 40 3A FD 76 41 33 C9 49 8B C6 45 85    .d$0@:.vA3.I..E.
fffff800`02c0ed50  E4 74 64 48 F7 40 10 00 F0 FF FF 74 0D 48 8B 40    .tdH.@.....t.H.@
fffff800`02c0ed60  08 FF C1 41 3B CC 72 EB EB 4D 48 83 64 24 20 00    ...A;.r..MH.d$ .
```

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is a pastebin, was in the middle of an edit but Scott beat me to it =p http://pastebin.com/Ay6pdAVV

Comment: upload the minidumps so that we can look at them with WinDbg

Comment: Where do I upload the minidumps to ?

Comment: skydrive, dropbox or a free "1 click hoster"

Comment: File uploaded to https://hotfile.com/dl/182033219/3e62f02/113012-32557-01_-_Copy.dmp.html

Answer (score 2):

Your Intel WLAN driver seems to be the cause:

```
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80002c0e477, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80002f03100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80002f031c0
 0000000000000000 Nonpaged pool

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
hal!HalpDmaNextContiguousPiece+103
fffff800`02c0e477 448b08          mov     r9d,dword ptr [rax]

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  firefox.exe
Call Site
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
hal!HalpDmaNextContiguousPiece
hal!HalpDmaMapScatterTransfer
hal!HalpMapTransfer
hal!IoMapTransfer
hal!HalpAllocateAdapterCallback
hal!IoFreeAdapterChannel
hal!HalAllocateAdapterChannel
hal!HalBuildScatterGatherList
ndis!NdisMAllocateNetBufferSGList
netw5v64
0x0
netw5v64
0x0
0x0

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\netw5v64.sys
Image name: netw5v64.sys
Timestamp:        Thu Mar 26 17:21:24 2009
```

so, update the driver:

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx?lang=eng

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I used the utility on the Intel site to locate an updated driver for my wireless network card.  I have not had a BoD since then (yesterday), so fingers crossed that this has solved the issues.